# In premillennialism, who returns to the earth with Jesus before his 1000 year reign?

Tags: revelation, second-coming, premillennialism

According to premillennialism, who exactly is coming with Jesus when He comes back to earth for the 1,000 years?

Is it the saved saints that didn't get the mark of the beast on their hands or foreheads, or were killed for still preaching the Word of God during the Tribulation?

Will the saved people that are in heaven as spirits that are coming back with Jesus in the second coming, that will be reunited with an imperishable body also be on earth with Christ for 1,000 years?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  To find out how we are different to other sites and what we look for in a well-researched question, please take our Tour: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

> Will the saved people that are in heaven as spirits … ?

That's a big assumption for a general category of Christianity.

Some denominations *do* believe this doctrine, but many others fail to find any biblical support for it.
Nowhere does the Bible ever say that people will go to Heaven when they die.

The Bible talks about death as "sleep", and teaches that the dead are awaiting resurrection.
A few, the elect, will be resurrected at Jesus's return ("the first resurrection"), while the rest of humanity have to wait until the end of the thousand years ("the second resurrection").

> … on earth with Christ for 1,000 years

Again, that's a big assumption for a general category of Christianity.

In this case though, it is one that *is* supported by a literal reading of the Bible.

---

The problem is, the denominations that believe the dead go to heaven (possibly via purgatory) and the denominations that believe that Jesus will rule on Earth with the newly resurrected elect for a thousand years, tend not to overlap.

Your problem arises from choosing doctrines from different, conflicting denominations.
That they don't fit together well, or even don't make sense, is to be expected.

Comment: tend not to overlap. Lol, that’s putting it delicately! (I know it’s probably tiresome, but a few key verses might help this answer) +1 anyway.